# getConfigurableAttributesAsArray causes fatal error

Tags: magento-1.9, import, fatal-error, script

I am trying to write a script that creates configurable products. Ive been using this as a guide: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/

When I get to this line:

```
$configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
```

The script crashes and kicks out this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/buyfrom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 283
```

Following [a comment on this page](http://www.sharpdotinc.com/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/), I changed that line to the following:

```
$possibleAttributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

But I am still getting this error. Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: What version of Magento? Have you re-indexed?

Comment: version 1.9.2 - reindexed, flushed cache, etc...

Comment: There is one (or multiple attributes) that seems to be invalid. Open up that `Configurable.php` file, and at the top of the `getConfigurableAttributesAsArray` function, add :  `if(!is_object($attribute->getProductAttribute())) { var_dump($attribute); continue; }` then inspect the output

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Your product *attribute_set_id* is set wrong. It may be set to a *attribute_set_id* that does not have the attribute you are trying to use included to its attribute set. If you dump your product you may see the attribute_set_id.

The solution is to set the attribute set to one that has the attribute included before calling the function.

So do something like this:

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(10);
// 10 is the Id of one of your attribute sets that has the attribute included
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```